# Python parsing the site gives <html></html>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, httpx

There is a website that I need to analyze
However, when I try to analyze it, I get the response `<html></html>`

Tried to change the useragent, cookie, doesn't help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import httpx

response = httpx.get('https://lolz.guru/market/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

print(response.text)
```

Comment: That's the same result I get.  Why do you think it should be something else?

Comment: The page in the browser looks completely different.

Comment: Sounds like the page uses javascript, which `httpx` does not support.

Comment: And what should I do in this case?

Comment: Use something other than `httpx`.

Comment: I guess the site has a protection against the type of requests, even curl can't get the page. I tried with the request module, and it giving the same result

Comment: Yes, the site definitely has some kind of protection and I can't figure out how to get around it

Comment: Have you tried using Selenium?

Comment: I can't connect cookies to Selenium

Comment: Why not?  Selenium uses a real browser, so it should handle cookies automatically.

Comment: I inserted cookies, refreshed the page and nothing happened

Comment: Without seeing how you inserted the cookies, and without knowing how that site is supposed to respond to those cookies, we can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`request_html`](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/), it has the ability to render JavaScript:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession


session = HTMLSession()
resp = session.get('https://lolz.guru/market/')

resp.html.render(sleep=1, keep_page=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.html.html, "lxml")

print(soup.text)
# print the whole page
```

You can install it using pip: `pip install requests-html`

Answer (score 0):

If that site requires a real browser, you could try to direct a real browser to retrieve the page and the data. [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) is a tool intended to test web applications, but in essence it can run scripts imitating user interaction with web browsers so the applications get checked.

There are nice tutorials out there, also for [using Selenium from Python](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/python-selenium-to-run-web-automation-test).

It also supports cookies: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/cookies/

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.example.com")

# Adds the cookie into current browser context
driver.add_cookie({"name": "key", "value": "value"})
```

Comment: I can't connect cookies to Selenium